# Using Cordova 5.0.0 Google Maps with Content Security Policy

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova

I m building Cordova Application for Android using Cordova 5.0.0. and I m using Google Maps without Plugin and it must be without plugin.
I include this script and meta tag .also Cordova using whitelist plugin.

```html
  <!-- Meta tag -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
  
   <!-- Google Maps-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

it's give me this error:

```js
 Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

Comment: Did any of the below work for you, @Nazir Dogan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this block to get that error away

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
default-src 'self' data: gap:
    *;
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
    *;
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
    *;
media-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
    *;
img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
    *;
connect-srv 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
    *
">
```

Comment: This is not a good idea as it leaves the content security policy wide open, it's kind of like shutting down your firewall rather than opening the one port you need.  See Italo Maia's answer below for a safer answer.

Answer (score 13):

Try the using the following content-security-policy:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self' data: gap:
            https://ssl.gstatic.com;
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
            https://*.gstatic.com https://*.googleapis.com;
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
        media-src *">
```

Google maps needs the rules defined for script-src as above with 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'. ; )

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer, as it does not leave the Content-Security-Policy wide open.  You also might have to add 'https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://maps.google.com/' to the script-src.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `<allow-navigation>` tags to your `config.xml` file if you want to allow navigation for other URLs. The following should work:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Just as a word of caution, the `<allow-intent>` line whitelists the entire network over HTTP and HTTPS, which might not be something you want in a production environment. You can check the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#cordova-plugin-whitelist) for more information. Failing that, if you have any other security libs in place, you might have to remove them as they could be blocking Google Maps.

Comment: I forgot to say this but I also added this.

Comment: Try removing and re-adding all of your plugins. You might also have to change the placement of your script tag.

Comment: I did your recommendation but its give me same result.

Answer (score 0):

Older post, but after a few teaks found the one that worked for me.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data gap  https://*.google.com  https://*.googleapis.com  https://*.gstatic.com  https://*.googleusercontent.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *">
```